# csvmapper - 'Module' object has no attribute 'DictMapper'

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, attributeerror

I'm using csvmapper with Python 2.7.8.

Running my script from the shell.

This is the basic [example on Github](https://github.com/samarjeet27/CSV-Mapper)

```
import csvmapper

mapper = csvmapper.DictMapper([
    [ 
        { 'name': 'firstName' } , 
        { 'name' : 'lastName' }, 
        { 'name': 'age', 'type':'int' }
    ]
])

parser = csvmapper.CSVParser('data.csv', mapper)
objects = parser.buildObject()
print '%s will be %d years old after 2 years' %(objects[0].firstName, (objects[0].age + 2))
```

I get the error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DictMapper'

After researching that error, I added this on line two

```
from csvmapper import DictMapper
```

Now I receive this error

> 'ImportError: cannot import name DictMapper

Could not find reference on Github to this error, very confused.

Comment: Have you named your own script `csvmapper`?

Comment: Wow. Now I feel silly. That's the answer, thanks kindall.